# How to save type as a variable and use it in cast

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
public class MyClass {...}

private void foo(MyClass _param)

void caller {
    Object obj = new MyClass();
    foo((MyClass)obj);
}
```

I want to mention `MyClass` only once and use it later as follows:

```
void caller {
    Class<?> clazz = MyClass.class;
    ...
    Object obj = new clazz();
    foo((clazz)obj); // compile error: "unknown class 'clazz'"
}
```

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: you should use 'MyClass' instead of clazz.

Comment: It's not fully clear to me what exactly you want, but: learn about generics: [Lesson: Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: @VimalBera I want to type `MyClass` only once in `caller`, i.e. save the type and then use it in casts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not. Create a method which do the cast for you.

```
private MyClass cast(Object obj)
{
    return (MyClass) obj;
}
```

This would be a more generic solution:

```
void caller() 
{
    Class<MyClass> clazz = MyClass.class;
    Object obj = new MyClass();
    foo(cast(obj, clazz));
}

private <T> T cast(Object obj, Class<T> clazz)
{
    return (T) obj;
}
```

In your example, you wrote `Object obj = new clazz();` this can be written as `MyClass obj = clazz.newInstance();`.

Comment: that's unfortunate =|

Comment: Class `java.lang.Class` already has a `cast` method that does (more or less) the same as the `cast` method you posted in your answer, so you could just write: `foo(clazz.cast(obj));`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jesper, I did it in my own code using `class.cast(obj)`:

```java
  public class MyClass {...}

  private void foo(MyClass _param)

  void caller {
    Class<?> clazz = MyClass.class;
    ...
    Object obj = new clazz();
    //foo((clazz)obj); // compile error: "unknown class 'clazz'"
    foo(clazz.cast(obj)); // <-- do this instead
  }
```